# too many arguments for format. C on eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, arguments, scanf

Dont know what im doing wrong. The program runs but doesnt do the mathematic formula correctly.Plz help

```
#include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include "input.h"

    int main(void) {
        float peso, altura, imc;
        desativarBufferConsole();
        printf("\ndigite o seu peso em Kg");
        scanf("%f", &peso);
        printf("\ndigite a sua altura em m");
        scanf("&f", &altura);
        imc = (peso)/(altura*altura);
        scanf("%f", &imc);
        printf("\no seu imc e: %f", imc);
        limpaBufferStdin();
        pausar();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Heh? Whre's the rest of the code?

Comment: `scanf("&f", &altura);`...WTH?

Comment: Aside from the missing code and syntax errors, you appear to be reading user input into the `imc` variable after you calculate it, thus overwriting the calculated value.

Answer (score 2):

Your have a syntax error in the following line:

```
scanf("&f", &altura);
```

The format specifier whould be `%f` not `&f`.

Therefore, change your line to:

```
scanf("%f", &altura);
```

Another thing I wanted to point out:

```
    imc = (peso)/(altura*altura);
    scanf("%f", &imc);
    printf("\no seu imc e: %f", imc);
```

Here, you do a calculation, store the value in `imc` and then you ask for input to be stored in `imc` again, losing the previous calculated value. This is a logic error that you should sort out yourself.